# How to search a XML file using the value in ARGV[1]

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to search a file using the value in the ARGV array. However using doc.at is not working. I have set the variable keyword to ARGV[1] and when given a value that prints to the console but when i try to puts the variable text to the console it comes up blank.

```
require 'nokogiri'

input = ARGV[0]
keyword = ARGV[1]

case input

when input = "list"
 doc = File.open("emails.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
 text = doc.at('record:contains("{keyword}")')
 puts text
 puts keyword



else 
puts "no"

end
```

Comment: your interpolation is wrong. `doc.at("record:contains('#{keyword}')")`. start with double `"` and interpolate with `#{}`

Comment: thanks for the help, cant believe I did not see that

Comment: Sure. added that as answer. You can accept that if it fixes the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string interpolation is wrong. 
Change it to:

```
doc.at("record:contains('#{keyword}')")
```

start with double `"` and interpolate with `#{}`